# how to stop toggle panel to push the rest of the content

Tags: jquery, css

im trying to make a slide panel that on toggle function it overlay the content but instead its pushing everything down!

```
.flip{
  display: inline;
}
.panel
{
    background: #999999;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 1% 0;
    display:none;
}
.panel,.flip
{
    float:right;
    text-align:center;
}
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".flip").click(function () {
        $(".panel").slideToggle(350);
    });
});
```

here is the very close sample of the code which i have problem with at jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/alinem/9yHSE/

(the Toggle button is at the top right corner)

and here is the my code live on page

http://ire.siload.com/

how can i make it overlay instead of pushing the content?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9yHSE/2/)

You need to give the sliding panel `position:absolute;`, offset its top by the height of your `nav`, so give it `top:40px`, give it a `z-index` of 1 and the content below (Slider) a `z-index` of 0

```
.panel {
    background: #999999;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 1% 0;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    top:40px;
}

.Slider {
    padding: 0px;
    z-index:0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: this great thank you, but still there is a minor problem...eventho the float is right, it still slide down at the left side of the screen!!

Comment: okay...this is so weird!! it worked on jsfiddle but when i applied the same thing to the website ..it shows up only for a few millisecond when slider is sliding then it fades when the slider is showing the pic!! it technically show up when slider is transmitting !! http://ire.siload.com/ there u can see whats happening to it!

Comment: Add `position:relative` and `z-index:0` to `.main`

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH....YOU ARE A LIFE SAVIOUR. it works on the website when i deployed it but it doesnt work on local !! is there something wrong with my visual studio or...!!!

Comment: If you have your answer in the context of the original question- you should accept it, it sounds like you now have grounds for a new question (VS related)